# Extracting a substring makes the for loop break in python

Tags: python

I am having a lot of trouble with a text file given to me that I need to parse. This is my third attempt at parsing it (I tried both C and php which seem to fail in different ways).

I have this extremely simple code :

```
    import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(['basin_stclair.txt']):
    print line[0:64]
```

For some reason the code exits after the first print.

If I print the lines whole then it never stops but the lines are still combined. (If I only let the loop run for one iteration I get two lines(14 floats).

The text file looks like this(Several hundred lines like this one, 7 floats) :

1.749766    3.735660    0.294098    310.461737  0.000000    0.231367    0.230505

When I copy the entire text in kate it gets all jumbled and lines combine.

The text file was made using excell on a windows machine. (I'm working on a linux box).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please paste the output for the following command: `hexdump -C basin_stclair.txt | head`

Comment: If you want to copy the first 64 or less columns of each line, you can do this pretty easily in vim.  Open the file in vim, then hit `g` `g` `|` `^V` `G` `6` `3` `l` `y`.  (note that `^V` means to hit CTRL-V as a single keystroke)  Now open a new file, for example with `:tabedit`, and paste it in with `p`.  Do `:w filename` to save.  This will only work as advertised if the last line of the file contains at least 64 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some problem with the newline characters in your file.  Try opening the file using Python's universal newline support:

```
for line in open('basin_stclair.txt', 'U'):
    print line[0:64]
```

Comment: This works, thank you! It makes sense that the character is break line.

Comment: +1 for identifying what is probably the problem. Note that `fileinput.input` (which the OP is using instead of `open`) has the same mode flag parameter.

Comment: @phooji: I know that this can also be done with `fileinput.input()`, but it seems a bit pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to print the first 64 lines? If so, try something like this:

```
i = 0
for line in fileinput.input(['basin_stclair.txt']):
  print line[0:64]
  if i > 63:
     break
  i = i + 1
```

Are you trying to print the first 64 characters of each line? Try something like this:

```
for line in fileinput.input(['basin_stclair.txt']):
    if len(line) > 63:
        print line[0:64]
```

Comment: I am trying to print the first 64 characters. Checking the length does not seem to work though. From what I gather every line read by python is essentially two lines separated by a unknown character.

Comment: @Stranger_in_the_night: See @Sven Marnach' suggestion. Since you're opening a file that was generated in Windows, which uses different line endings than Linux does, you may want to use 'open' with universal newline support.

Comment: It is safe to print this slice `line[0:64]`, or even just `line[:64]` even if there are fewer than 64 characters in line, so there is no need to verify the line length first.

Comment: @Paul McGuire: Good point. I guess the flavor text should've been 'are you trying to avoid printing lines that have fewer characters' -- it wasn't entirely clear at the time whether the OP wanted to print all lines.